# PHP (Preg_match)

Tags: php

Gostaria que ajudassem a definir o meu `preg_match`.

Isto será para a criação de um formulario textarea `$_POST['text']`.

Eu quero que o pregmatch apenas aceite:
Traços, Pontos, Barras, + e -, virgulas, espaços, numeros, letras, # e *.

```
preg_replace("", $data);
```

Comment: Isso parece me um pouco vago. Qual o formato dos dados de entrada ? Não interessa a ordem dos carateres a aceitar ?

Comment: isto é para um formulario textarea... se o utilizador inserir outros caracters a nao ser os que eu falei, da erro.

Comment: Poderia ajudar? è para a escola :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi você quer que o `preg_match` valide se contém apenas os seguintes tipos de caracteres:

- traços
- pontos
- barras
- sinal de `+`
- sinal de `-`
- virgulas
- espaços
- numeros
- letras
- `#` (hash)
- `*` (asterisco)

Pode usar a seguinte [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
^[a-z0-9\-+, .\#*\\/]+$
```

No `preg_match` ficaria:

```
if (empty($_POST['text'])) {
    echo 'Não digitou nada';
} else {
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    if (preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\-+, .\#*\\/]+$#i', $text)) {
        echo 'Validou';
    } else {
        echo 'Não validou';
    }
}
```

---

### Explicando a regex

Essa regex é bem simples:

- o as chavetas `[...]` e tudo que for dentro delas será aceito (irá fazer o "match")
- o sinal de `^` indica que deve começar exatamente com a expressão a seguir
- o sinal de `$` indica que deve terminar exatamente com a expressão anterior
- O sinal de `+` entre o `]` e o `$` (`...]+$`) indica que que deve ter o formato do que tem dentro de `[...]` até encontrar a próxima expressão, como não tem expressão, só o `$` então termina ali, (independente da quantidade de carácteres)

Explicações extras:

- o `a-z` indica que pode conter de A á Z
- o `\d` indica que pode conter de 0 á 9 (é equivalente a digitar `0-9`)
- O `\-` indica de que pode conter hífens (tracinho `-`), a barra é pra escapar e não misturar com algum atalho de expressão
- `\\` é para aceitar barras invertidas, usasse duas barras para que o regex não pense que você esta tentando escapar a proxima expressão
- O `i` em `#...#i` é para considerar tanto letras maiúsculas quanto minusculas

```
^[a-z\d\-+, .\#*\\/]+$
^  ^                ^^
.  .                ..
.  .                .... Termina exatamente com a expressão anterior
.  .                .
.  .                .... busca até o "final" ou até a próxima expressão
.  .
.  ..................... tudo que estiver dentro de `[...]` será valido
.
........................ deve começar exatamente com a próxima expressão
```

Comment: Exato, o preg_match tem de validar um POST com esses caracters pedidos.

Comment: Esqueceu-se de por o $text no preg_match, mas ficaria assim certo: preg_match('....', $test)) correcto?

Comment: @Jonnhypi corrigi, também tinha fiz umas melhoras na regex, copia novamente por favor.

Comment: Teoricamente o circunflexo indica o início da linha(string). http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/circunflexo.html#2_3_1

Comment: @MarcosXavier o sentido é esse mesmo, se refere a próxima expressão de qualquer forma, "deve começar" = "a partir do começo da linha" :]

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento entendo e concordo mas para quem está iniciando, do modo que foi descrito, pode não entender dessa forma.

Comment: @MarcosXavier a expressão a seguir é o que vem depois do `^`.

Comment: Inclusive, parabéns pela ótima resposta.

Comment: Considere a seguinte ER https://regexr.com/3o443. Um iniciante poderia entender que os demais "asd" casariam com a ER. Não estou dizendo que está errado, e sim que pode gerar interpretação errônea especialmente para iniciantes.

Comment: @MarcosXavier a expressão a seguir é apenas `asd` e não `asdasdasdasd` dentro da regex, estou falando de expressões de regex e não da string.